# How we get record for particular user using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to fetch all records from database where my order number is equal, but when am trying to use where condition then its show null value please tell me what can I do.

model code:

```
public function get_products()  
{

    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('product');
    $this->db->select('sku');
    $this->db->select('price');
    $this->db->select('qty');
    $this->db->select('tax');
    $this->db->select('total');
    $this->db->from('data');
    $this->db->where('order',$this->input->post('order'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($result = $query->result_array())
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use $this->db->last_query(); to debug what is going in you query

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

**MODEL:**

```
function single_user_data($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('');
    $this->db->from('user');            
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $query=$this->db->get()->result();
    return $query;  
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function user_data_get()
    {
        $user_id=$this->input->post('id');  
        $data['user_data']=$this->User_Model->single_user_data($user_id);   
        $this->load->view('edit_user.php',$data);   
    }
```

Comment: cr05s19xx am using your code but sill i have same problem order is null

Comment: you echo your post user id value if u get so this code run perfactly and in your controller load your model

Comment: I want to fetch record using order because, I need to record according to order not id

Comment: use controller this is a wrong way . Follow mvc structure.

Comment: You put your where condition this type -- if(!empty($this->input->post('order')))
{
 $this->db->where('order',$this->input->post('order')); 
}

Answer (score 0):

I really am not a fan of CodeIgniter's magic functions to help in database scripting because I can't really control what is happening. But if this might help, I am writing a raw MySQL query for you. This might prove to be a little faster (for reasons I will explain later)

#### CONTROLLER

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    //.... some functions come here

    public function user_data_get()
    {
        $this->load->model('Get_user_model');
        $user_data = $this->Get_user_model->get_product($this->input->post('order'));
    }
}
```

#### MODEL

```
class Get_user_model extends CI_Model
{
    //..some code comes here

    public function get_product($order)
    {
        $order = $this->db->escape($order);    // Prevention against SQL injection

        $query = $this->db->query("
            SELECT `product`, `sku`, `price`, `qty`, `tax`, `total` FROM `data`
            WHERE `order` = " . $order . " LIMIT 1");
    }
}
```

The results in the model can then be obtained from the `$query` variable (it will be in an object form). To get the result in an array form, you can run `$data = $query->row_array()` to push the results into a variable `$data` as an array.

If the results may return more than 1 row, then you should take out the `LIMIT 1` expression and use a `foreach` loop to get the results.

Hope it answers your question